# Yii2 Nav::widget убрать ul, li

Tags: php, yii2

Как корректно убрать теги списка `ul` , `li` из выдачи виджетом?
Пример

---

Виджет

```
echo Nav::widget([
  'options' => ['class' => 'nav nav-tabs border-0 flex-column flex-lg-row'],
  'encodeLabels' => false,
  'items' => $items
])
```

выдаёт структуру вида

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Мне же нужна выдача такого вида

```
<div class="my_dropdown_class">
 <a href="#">Link</a>
 <a href="#">Link</a>
 <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Переопределите метод который отвечает за вывод и будет вам счастье.

Comment: За смену `ul` возможно отвечает `'container' => 'div'`, но могу ошибаться, за `li`, скорее придется переписать шаблон вывода.